# How to get the timeslots from the start time and end time in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timeslots

I have a pandas dataframe where it has start_time, end_time and booking duration.

Please find below example dataframe

| id | Start_time | End_time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 09:30:00 | 0 days 0:30:00 |
| 2 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 12:10:00 | 0 days 3:10:00 |
| 3 | 2013-11-20 10:00:00 | 2013-11-20 11:00:00 | 0 days 1:00:00 |
| 4 | 2013-11-20 08:00:00 | 2013-11-20 09:40:00 | 0 days 1:40:00 |

I am trying to get the timeslots from the above dataframe

Expected output:

| id | Start_time | End_time | Duration | Timeslots |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 09:30:00 | 0 days 0:30:00 | 9 - 10 |
| 2 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 12:10:00 | 0 days 3:10:00 | 9-10 |
| 2 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 12:10:00 | 0 days 3:10:00 | 10-11 |
| 2 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 12:10:00 | 0 days 3:10:00 | 11-12 |
| 3 | 2013-11-20 10:00:00 | 2013-11-20 11:00:00 | 0 days 1:00:00 | 10 - 11 |
| 4 | 2013-11-20 08:00:00 | 2013-11-20 09:40:00 | 0 days 1:40:00 | 8-9 |
| 4 | 2013-11-20 08:00:00 | 2013-11-20 09:40:00 | 0 days 1:40:00 | 9-10 |

What I have tried till now

I can get the slots from start_time and end_time  but i am missing the expected output

| id | Start_time | End_time | Duration | TimeSlot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 09:30:00 | 0 days 0:30:00 | 9-9:30 |
| 2 | 2013-11-20 09:00:00 | 2013-11-20 12:10:00 | 0 days 3:10:00 | 9-12:10 |
| 3 | 2013-11-20 10:00:00 | 2013-11-20 11:00:00 | 0 days 1:00:00 | 10-11 |
| 4 | 2013-11-20 08:00:00 | 2013-11-20 09:40:00 | 0 days 1:40:00 | 8 - 9:40 |

Can anyone give some hints please

Comment: I think you miss one slot for the id 2: 12-13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def get_slots(row):
    dti = pd.date_range(row['Start_time'].floor('H'), 
                        row['End_time'].ceil('H'), freq='H')
    return [f"{s.hour:02}-{e.hour:02}" for s, e in zip(dti, dti[1:])]
    
out = df.assign(Timeslots=df.apply(get_slots, axis=1)).explode('Timeslots')
print(out)

# Output:
   id          Start_time            End_time        Duration Timeslots
0   1 2013-11-20 09:00:00 2013-11-20 09:30:00 0 days 00:30:00     09-10
1   2 2013-11-20 09:00:00 2013-11-20 12:10:00 0 days 03:10:00     09-10
1   2 2013-11-20 09:00:00 2013-11-20 12:10:00 0 days 03:10:00     10-11
1   2 2013-11-20 09:00:00 2013-11-20 12:10:00 0 days 03:10:00     11-12
1   2 2013-11-20 09:00:00 2013-11-20 12:10:00 0 days 03:10:00     12-13
2   3 2013-11-20 10:00:00 2013-11-20 11:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     10-11
3   4 2013-11-20 08:00:00 2013-11-20 09:40:00 0 days 01:40:00     08-09
3   4 2013-11-20 08:00:00 2013-11-20 09:40:00 0 days 01:40:00     09-10
```

Setup to be reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp, Timedelta

data = {
'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
'Start_time': [Timestamp('2013-11-20 09:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-11-20 09:00:00'), 
               Timestamp('2013-11-20 10:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-11-20 08:00:00')], 
'End_time': [Timestamp('2013-11-20 09:30:00'), Timestamp('2013-11-20 12:10:00'),
             Timestamp('2013-11-20 11:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-11-20 09:40:00')],
'Duration': [Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00'), Timedelta('0 days 03:10:00'),
             Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 01:40:00')]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```